# main method not being executed

Tags: c

Here is a program to find prime numbers using sieve of Eratosthenes. The program is compiling but on execution, it becomes non responsive.The print statement itself is not executed. Can I know where I have gone wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the range");
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int j;
    int a[--n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i]=i+2;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            if(a[i])
            {
                    printf("%d",a[i]);
                    for(j=2;(i*j)<n;j++)
                            a[i*j]=0;
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "sieve of Eratosthenes"? what's that?

Comment: debuggers are great!!

Comment: Try just typing a number into your program and hitting return.  Don't forget to end output that you want to see with a newline.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Are you in jest, or Complaining About Capitalization?  Or ... for real?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It's an [elementary-math approach to find prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - seriously? You can't select some text then right-click and select `Search Google for 'sieve of Eratosthenes'`?

Comment: In addition to Jonathan: add `fflush(stdout)` after the first `printf`.

Comment: Usually printf flushes stdout with '\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is infinite looping the first time through the loop.

When i = 0 this loop never ends:

```
for(j=2;(i*j)<n;j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `printf` call might be being buffered which means it might not actually be printed until the buffer fills up or a newline is encountered.

Try adding a newline to the end of your string or call `fprintf(stderr, ...)` instead (which isn't buffered).